# What does "a composer of no ordinary merit" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm not sure I'm grasping the meaning of the last two words.

> My friend was an enthusiastic musician, being himself not only a very capable performer but a composer of no ordinary merit.

Comment: It means he was a good composer -- better than average.

Comment: ab2 is correct, but it's easy to see why a reader might find the expression bewildering. One can easily imagine Churchill telling some hapless author "You are a writer of no ordinary talent"—and mean it in the sense of "You do not possess even ordinary talent." But again, that's not the way the phrase is used in normal English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally the definition of [Merit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/merit) in the OED refers to the same type of example:

> The quality of being particularly good or worthy, especially so as to deserve praise or reward:
>
> (for example) composers of outstanding merit

So what does this have to do with your example? It's an instance of a particular writing style which doesn't stab directly at what the writer is trying to say. Instead it takes a slightly around-about path. Usually this is done to add a bit of variety to the language.

The writer is saying that the friend is a composer who has merit; "the quality of being good". But he is not ***just*** good in the "ordinary" way that composers who have merit are; he exceeds that. His is, therefore, "of no ordinary merit" but rather of outstanding merit, such as those mentioned in the OED example.

This meaning is understood almost intuitively by someone who is well versed in English, but for those who have English as a second language it's understandable why it may not be clear. Obviously if the "merit" is something other than "ordinary merit" it could be something greater, or it could be something lesser. However in this case it is almost certain that the writer meant to say that it's something greater. He or she has just picked a more restrained way of saying it.

Comment: I have read a lot of this book which i quoted that sentence from so i'm kind of know the way he describes. But i don't know about music and it's my second language as you said.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere there's a name for the literary device of negating a good or bad quality to make it bad or good, respectively. Do you happen to know the name for that?

Comment: @Yay: That's probably better off as a separate question, as it doesn't really relate to this one. The writer in this case isn't inverting or negating the meaning, merely "soft pedalling" the way s/he conveys the praise. It's rather late at night in my part of the world and my synapses may not be firing as well as they might, but off hand the only example I can think of is sarcasm, such as Marc Antony's statement that "Brutus is an honourable man" from Shakespeare. However that runs only one way; it doesn't make a bad quality good.

Comment: @Alan I just found it! It's a *litotes*. According to the answer provided to the question [The meaning of "not without some merit"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298866/the-meaning-of-not-without-some-merit?rq=1), litotes is a "backwards way saying something positive or negative". Another example given is "There was no small crowd at the protest rally." It may be useful to add that to your asnwer.

Comment: A litotes is pretty much the exact *opposite* of what was written here. It employs irony. There is no irony here. "Not without some merit" is a statement which grudgingly admits that there *is* merit, but implies that it is of a lesser value than one might have hoped for or expected. The sentence in this question does not negate the *merit* (as a litotes expression would), it states that the merit is not *ordinary*. The fact that this is a wholly positive assertion, one which is merely understated, is clear from the first part of the sentence.